# Center input field with specific size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this template:

http://responsivewebinc.com/premium/chandler/multi/

If you scroll down a bit you find this section:

**Web Designing & Development**

What i want is to place a input filed above that 2 buttons with a resonable size. Approx as long as the text above is.

I can't figure out how to do that. I tried many thing but it either is not centerd, or it is too big (full page width).

For example if i place this outside of the container div it has the perfect size but is not centered:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <form role="form">
                <!-- Form Group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="Enter-name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried many other things as well but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand your problem to be:

You want an input between the paragraph text and the buttons, that is approximately the width of the paragraph text, that responds to changing screen sizes and that is positioned in the center.

If that's the case, I would just add a class to my custom-styles.css file for that input that uses the same properties as the paragraph text above it, along with whatever styles you want to use from Bootsrap.

```
.my-input{
max-width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But it fine if it's a predefined size from bootstrap. However your code does not change anything. Everything is as before. Did you tried it with FireBug? Thanks

Comment: Ah nevermind it works fine. I had to place it in the container. I just wonder if it's possible to do something like that without addidional css? There are already predefined classes for the size but if i use them withour your code it does not work. THanks

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap generally requires some additional CSS to get your custom theme to render.  The limitation in your case is the p.hero style is created by the template developer, not Bootstrap.  If you want to mirror that behavior, you have to apply a similar style.  You might be able to fake it with Bootstrap using a narrower .col-x-y style combined with the offset style col-x-offset-y to center it, but that requires a lot more html and it may be harder to get it right-sized.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the explanation. I am a backend developer so i have a hard time with CSS in genral. Thank for your help, much appreciated.